# jquery unable to read json response (using $.post)

Tags: jquery, json, http-post

I am submitting a post request with data type json. 
I am able to see json response in fiddrel but jquery is not able to parse that.

Here is my code:

```
$("#jsonTestCasePost").click(function(){
        var requestType = $("#requestType").val();
        $('#result').val(requestType);
        debugger;
        $.post("http://localhost/api/number/substract", {numberA:"32",numberB:"10"},
         function(data){
            debugger;
            $('#result').val(data);
         }, requestType);
});
```

This is my raw response text in fiddler.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 15
Server: Jetty(6.1.11)

{"result":"22"}
```

In jquery done function I see following values:

```
status: 0
statusTex: "", 
responses: {}
headers: ""
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: what does `var requestType` contains? `json`?

Comment: i am creating a test page where it allows to select json or xml

Comment: Are you making your request to the same server your page is on?  Eg, if you are requesting `http://localhost/api/number/substract`, is your current requesting page url at `http://localhost`?

Comment: no I wasn't. After moving my test page under localhost I am able to see correct response. Thanks.. Would you mind posting yours comment as an answer? I have wasted my whole morning debugging this. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here's my comment in the form of an answer:

You are probably falling victim to restrictions due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  Make sure your request is being sent to the same server your page is on. Eg, if you are requesting `http://localhost/api/number/substract`, your current requesting page must be at `http://localhost`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use data's result property:

```
$('#result').val(data.result);
```

Answer (score 1):

in the case you are doing `cross browser` request use jquery's `ajax`

```
$.ajax({
url:'http://localhost/api/number/substract',
type:'POST',
data:{numberA:"32",numberB:"10"},
dataType:'json',
async:false,
cache:false,
crossDomain:true,
success:function(data){
$('#result').val(data.result);    
},
error:function(jxhr){
console.log(jxhr.responseText);
}   

});
```

Comment: I think jquery's $.post uses $.ajax at the end.. Isnt it?

Comment: `post`  is a shorthand Ajax function have a look here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/, but `$.ajax` gives more options like `crossDomain` etc

Answer (score 0):

Making request from the same server solved my problem. Thanks gilly3 for you comment.